# Issues Parsing Timestamp data to Local Date and Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express

I'm having some trouble getting the local date and time for the timestamps stored in a JSON file.

the method `getData()` is supposed to get all the data from the JSON file including the dates formated as "YYYY-mm-dd" and return it to be loaded to a webpage. But the Dates just load as the string of numbers instead of the dates in a human readable format (ie. YYYY-mm-dd).

## JSON data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "CastAway",
    "description": "Cast movies, music, or pictures to any TV",
    "createdDate": 1629343012430,
    "lastUpdated": 1629343012430
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Turn",
    "description": "Find directions to new destinations",
    "createdDate": 1629343012430,
    "lastUpdated": 1629343012430
  }
]
```

## CODE

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

/**
 * Logic for reading and writing project data
 */
class ProjectService {
  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param {*} datafile Path to a JSOn file that contains the project data
   */
  constructor(datafile) {
    this.datafile = datafile;
  }

  // adding data to JSON file
  async addEntry(name, description) {
    const data = (await this.getData()) || [];
    const createdDate = Date.now();
    const lastUpdated = Date.now();
    const id = 0;
    data.unshift({ id, name, description, createdDate, lastUpdated });
    return writeFile(this.datafile, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  async getList() {
    const data = await this.getData();
    for (let i in data) {
      data[i]['createdDate'] = new Date(data[i]['createdDate']);
      data[i]['lastUpdated'] = new Date(data[i]['lastUpdated']);
    }
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }

  //reading data from JSON file
  async getData() {
    const data = await readFile(this.datafile, 'utf8');
    if (!data) return [];
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to recreate the dates after calling JSON.parse with something like following:

```
var data = await getData();
var parsedCreatedDate = new Date(data[0]['createdDate']);
var parsedlastUpdated = new Date(data[0]['lastUpdated']);
```

Comment: see code for changes. I've added method `getList()` which parses the data and outputs the correct date in the `console.log(data);` output, but it does not carry over to the website.